# Prove if $x,y$ integers then there are $p,q$ integers such that $xy = p^2 - q^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> - Prove that if $x$ and $y$ are any two integers which are both even or both odd then there are integers $p$ and $q$ such that $xy = p^2 - q^2$.
> - Prove that if n is an integer which is $2 \mod 4$ then $n$ cannot be written in the form $p^2 - q^2$ for integers $p$ and $q$.

I'm really stuck what to do on the first one. I know its possible as $xy$ will be even and $p^2 - q^2$ will be even, but I don't know how to show it will equal. Can someone give me a hint?

For the second one, I have said this:

1) If $p,q$ are odd then we get $p,q \equiv 1 \mod 4 \implies p^2, q^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. So we then get $p^2 - q^2 \equiv 1 - 1 \mod 4 \equiv 0 \mod 4$.

2) If $p,q$ are even then we get $p,q \equiv 0 \mod 4 \implies p^2, q^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and so $p^2 - q^2 \equiv 0 - 0 = 0 \mod 4$.

3) Finally, if one of $p,q$ is odd and the other even, then wlg, $p \equiv 1 \mod 4 \implies p^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and $q \equiv 0 \mod 4 \implies q^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and so we get $p^2 - q^2 \equiv 1 - 0 = 1 \mod 4$.

Which shows that with all combinations of $p,q$ even or odd, it isn't possible to get $2 \mod 4$. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you could try an argument using that $xy = \frac{1}{4} ((x-y)^2 + (x+y)^2)$ for any $x, y$ (ie. what the first answer said)?

Comment: @AndrewD Is that an identity I should just know? Going from right to left, I can expand and see that it's correct, but going from left to right, is that something that I should just know?

Comment: It is probably better to just memorise it - it's what I did when I first came across a question requiring it (I was never able to spot it). Also, the form of the identity I stated was wrong; it should be $xy = \frac{1}{4} ((x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, note that if $x$ and $y$ are even or odd, $$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 = xy,$$ and both of $\dfrac{x+y}{2}$ and $\dfrac{x-y}{2}$ are integers.

Your argument for the second question looks mostly good: you can't claim that $p,q$ are $0$ or $1$ mod $4$, but this does always hold for their squares, so it winds up working.

Comment: Damn you man!! I was just about to post my first answer, and you wrapped it up cleanly.

Comment: @Cocopuffs Ok, thank you, I'll try that first proof now. For the second one, how would I know their squares are $0,1 \mod 4$? I would've just said if $p \equiv 2 \mod 4 \implies p^2 \equiv 2 \mod 4$, which is now clearly wrong (and I can check it with say $p - 6$). Is it just an identity I should remember?

Comment: @Kaish $(2n)^2=4n^2,(2n+1)^2=4(n^2+n)+1$

Comment: @Mike Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: @Kaish In other words: $0^2 \equiv 0$, $1^2 \equiv 1$, $2^2 \equiv 0$, $3^2 \equiv 1$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, consider the difference of two squares: $$xy=(p-q)(p+q)$$
So let, say, $p-q=x$ and $p+q=y$. Thus $2p=x+y \implies p=\frac{x+y}{2} \implies q=\frac{y-x}{2}$
$p,q$ must be integers since, by the condition, $x+y$ and $y-x$ are even.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm x\equiv y\,\ (mod\ 2)\:\Rightarrow\:x\, =\, y\!+\!2n\:\Rightarrow\: x\!-\!n\, =\, y\!+\!n\, =:\, z\:\Rightarrow\: x\,y\, =\, (z\!+\!n)(z\!-\!n)\, =\, z^2\!-\!n^2$